# Implement sharedPreferences in my application

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am making an android app for news.
I would like to make an option that will allow someone to like a news or a comment, and later, if someone tries to do it from the same phone, application should not allow that.

I know this should be done by **sharedpreferences** but I do not know how to store multiple ID  of news that user liked and later how to check wether id of news someone would like to like is already saved in sharedpreferences.

Any help would be appreciate.

Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my syntax is correct

```
// Retrieve and hold the contents of the preferences file 'name'
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(String name , int mode) 

SharedPreferences.Editor spEdit = sp.edit();

// key is ID
spEdit.putInt (String key, int value)


// don't forget
spEdit.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to store the `news id` that has been commented upon in the SharedPreferences and check against it.

Application shared preferences can be fetched using `getSharedPreferences()` method...

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                                                   "PrefsFile", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

We need an `SharedPreferences.Editor` to edit `sharedpreference` values...

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit()
```

[**Android ShredPreferences DOCS**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) will help you to understand better.

For your case, as mentioned earlier, you can use store the `news id` and check against it everytime to validate. (Not sure if this is the best way, but its a start to point you in the right direction.)

You can store the `news id` like this...

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                                                   "PrefsFile", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putInt("newsId", 108); // 108 is the news id and "newsId" is the variable name
editor.commit();
```

You can read it back like this...

```
int newsId = 0;
// check if the value exists in sharedpreferences
if(prefs.contains("newsId")) {
    newsId = prefs.getInt("newsId", 0);
}

// do your stuff!
```

Hope this helps!